# I can not insert data into database (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

When i add data into database. I get message error:

```
Field 'order' doesn't have a default value
INSERT INTO `pages` (`title`, `slug`, `body`, `parent_id`) VALUES ('About', 'Abot', 'About', 5)
```

MY_Model:

```
public function save($data, $id = NULL){

// Insert
    if ($id === NULL) {
    !isset($data[$this->_primary_key]) || $data[$this->_primary_key] = NULL;
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->insert($this->_table_name);

    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
}
// Update
else {
    $filter = $this->_primary_filter;
    $id = $filter($id);
    $this->db->set($data);
    $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
    $this->db->update($this->_table_name);
}

return $id;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function edit($id = NULL) {

    // Fetch a page or set a new one
    if($id) {
        $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['page']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'page could not be found';
    } else {
        $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_new();
    }

    // Pages for dropdown
    $this->data['pages_no_parents'] = $this->page_m->get_no_parents();
    //dump($this->data['pages_no_parents']);

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->page_m->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        //We can login and redirect
        $data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array('title', 'slug', 'body', 'parent_id'));
        $this->page_m->save($data, $id);
        redirect('admin/page');
    }
    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/page/edit';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

database:

```
 id | title    | slug    | order | body | parent_id
 1  | Homepage |  /      |    1  | abc  |  0
 2  | About    | contact |    0  | abc  |  0
```

when i run query in phpmyadmin:

```
INSERT INTO `pages` (`title`, `slug`, `body`, `parent_id`) VALUES ('About', 'Abot', 'About', 5)
```

it's ok.

Comment: give a default value to the `order` column..

Comment: But when i run query in phpmyadmin (do not order column) it still run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either insert some value for order

```
INSERT INTO `pages` (`title`, `slug`, `order`, `body`, `parent_id`) VALUES ('About', 'Abot', NULL, 'About', 5)
```

or change the table to have a default value

```
ALTER TABLE `pages` CHANGE `status` `status` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'whatever default you want';
```

Comment: But when i run query in phpmyadmin (do not order column) :  INSERT INTO `pages` (`title`, `slug`, `body`, `parent_id`) VALUES ('About', 'Abot', 'About', 5) it's insert success! and order column is 0 value. I following buld a cms in codeigniter on tutlus.

Comment: What is the CREATE TABLE syntax for that table?

Comment: I used migration to create it.         
 public function up()
 {
 $this->dbforge->add_field(array(
 'id' => array(
  'type' => 'INT',
  'constraint' => 11,
  'unsigned' => TRUE,
  'auto_increment' => TRUE
  ),
 'title' => array(
  'type' => 'VARCHAR',
  'constraint' => '100',
  ),
 'slug' => array(
  'type' => 'VARCHAR',
  constraint' => '100',
  ),
      'order' => array(
  'type' => 'INT',
  'constraint' => '11'
            ),
     'body' => array(
 'type' => 'TEXT',
        ),
 ));

Comment: The problem is that doesn't reveal the details of the table. Many SQL editors have a way to show the CREATE TABLE syntax on existing tables.

Comment: I have add order column.     $data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array('title', 'slug', 'order', 'body', 'parent_id')); and added success. Thank's.